# How to set form valid by condition?

Tags: angular, angular5

I have validation form:

```
public initStep6() {
    return this.fb.group({
      'name': ['', [Validators.required]]
    });
  }
```

Also I have checkbox on the page, if it is checked form should be valid even if filed name is empty.

How to make form valid without filling fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding correctly, you want the form to be valid if either name has a value OR the checkbox (which you didn't include in the form group) is checked. You can use a custom `ValidatorFn` function on the `FormGroup` to check for values across multiple fields. This is effectively from the [Cross Field Validation](https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#cross-field-validation) example in the form validation documentation. It would look something like this:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormControl, ValidationErrors, ValidatorFn, FormBuilder, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

const myValidator: ValidatorFn = (formGroup: FormGroup): ValidationErrors | null => {
  // get controls
  const name = formGroup.get('name');
  const myCheckbox = formGroup.get('myCheckbox');

  // validate however needed, e.g. length/pattern/etc
  const isNameValid: boolean = name && name.value && name.value.length > 0;
  const isCheckboxValid: boolean = myCheckbox && myCheckbox.value && myCheckbox.value === true;

  // return null if valid otherwise return object with custom key/value
  return (isNameValid || isCheckboxValid) ? null : { 'formValid': false };
};

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  myFormGroup: FormGroup;
  name = 'Angular';

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) { }

  onSubmit() {
    console.log('submitted!');
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    // key thing here is passing the ValidatorFn as the 2nd argument to expose the FormGroup in the ValidatorFn rather than a FormControl
    this.myFormGroup = new FormGroup({
      'name': new FormControl(),
      'myCheckbox': new FormControl()
    }, { validators: myValidator });
  }
}
```

Template:

```
<form [formGroup]="myFormGroup" *ngIf="myFormGroup" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
  <div>
    <label for="name">Name:</label>
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" formControlName="name" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <label for="myCheckbox">My Checkbox:</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="myCheckbox" id="myCheckbox" formControlName="myCheckbox" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <button type="submit" [disabled]="!myFormGroup.valid">Submit!</button>
  </div>

  <div *ngIf="myFormGroup.errors">
    {{myFormGroup.errors | json}}
  </div>
</form>
```

I've created a [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ogsfea) to demonstrate the functionality including disabling submit if form is invalid.

Hopefully that helps! If this isn't what you are looking for you really need to add more information to your question.

Comment: You can not get some element of form using `control`. It belong only for concerete control which is validated

Comment: `control` was a poor name I've updated the naming in my answer from `control` to `formGroup` to make it more semantically correct, but with how the `ValidatorFn` was passed to `FormGroup` creation as the 2nd argument, it exposes the form group allowing you to get any of the controls. If the `ValidatorFn` was passed as an argument to `FormControl`, then yes you would only have access to the individual control. In this case though, because it was passed like `new FormGroup({ }, { validators: myValidator })`, you get access to the `FormGroup` and can use method `get()` to access controls. Thanks!